# Getting S3 to always include a Vary header in its response

Tags: amazon-s3, http-headers, cors, cdn

I have CORS headers set up on S3, and when a browser makes a CORS request (i.e. includes an `Origin` header), S3 adds all the right headers to the response, including a `Vary` header. However, if the request does not include an `Origin` header, the response does not include a `Vary` header, which leaves intermediate caches (such as CDNs) free to cache the response and serve it when a later request comes in, even if that later request adds an `Origin` header.

How can I get S3 to always return a `Vary` header?

Comment: The problem has also been reported on the [AWS S3 Forums](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=555417&#555417)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The *why* is long-winded, but the short answer is: you can't. Not currently, anyway.

[TL;DR]

In S3, `Vary` is not a user-configurable header. While S3 can deliver CORS headers, CloudFront does not have explicit support for it.

If your end-goal is to deliver CORS-enables content from CloudFront using S3 as your source, I ended up working around the issue by deploying an app that sits between S3 and CloudFront, which proxies the requests and always adds the correct CORS headers to S3's response so that CloudFront caches the correct data.

Pros:

- CloudFront caches the CORS response headers along with the S3 data.
- CloudFront continues to work with 100% performance.
- The proxy app is very small and can be run on a t1.micro.

Cons:

- Not as straightforward as S3+CloudFront working together properly for CORS requests.
- Writing and deploying the app.

Comment: Actually, if you look at the "Related" questions to the right, you'll see several questions that include answers.

Comment: I'm not using CloudFront. I don't see any "Related" questions explaining how to get S3 to always send a `Vary` header.

Comment: In that case, the answer is "no". You cannot force S3 to always send a Vary header. See http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTCommonResponseHeaders.html and http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTObjectGET.html for more information about the response headers that S3 returns.